# How does one log into a Windows server, via RDP, using a Microsoft account with 2FA enabled?

Tags: windows, rdp

My client runs a Windows server, and has added me to it using my Microsoft account. I do not have physical access to this server. RDP is giving me authentication errors if I try to connect, which are related to the two factor authentication on my account. I cannot find anything in the Remote Desktop Connection client within my Windows 11 system that looks related to 2FA requests.

How do I, completely remotely, authenticate to RDP using this Microsoft account, without disabling 2FA?

Comment: How about posting a screenshot of the error or message?

Comment: It doesn't say anything more than "The logon attempt failed".

Comment: Then how is it related to two factor authentication?

Comment: Because I've indepedently verified that the credentials were otherwise correct (via logging into accounts.microsoft.com in a fresh browser profile), and have also independently verified (via Slack message) that I'm also listed as a user on that server. I'm allowed in, my password manager has the right password, only thing left I know of by process of elimination is 2FA.

Comment: What Windows Server edition is the server running? How did they add your Microsoft account? By Microsoft account do you mean Office 365 account? I'm not aware that you can log into Windows Server with a Microsoft account, other than in Windows Server Essentials.

Comment: I'm sorry, but those aren't questions I have answers for, I'm a Linux person trying to deploy something on Windows. All I know is "It's the same Microsoft account I used to log into my one Windows computer for video games". I'm not an Office 365 user, though, I can confirm that much.

Answer (score 0):

We've ended up working around this by creating a local account for myself to work with instead. I'm certain there's a way to make this work though, so I'm not flagging myself as the "resolved" answer.